# layer-list shape + bitmap on top with padding

Tags: java, android, bitmap, layer-list

I Try to center a drawable bitmap within a shape with padding, using layer-list.
But i can't get padding around the image.
THis is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#ffffffff"
                android:endColor="#ffbab8b9"
                android:startColor="#ffcfccce" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1px"
                android:color="#A0A0A0" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Does someone have an idea how to center a bitmap (for scaling) with padding?

Right now the bottom,left,... parameters are just ignored. The bitmap is scaled 100% within the Button.

I need it for a Button and can't use an ImageButton here.
Also the Button don't have text in that special case, so compoundDrawable will also not work. I need to do it with a Button.

Best regards,
Juergen

Comment: If your Button does not have text, then can you explain why you can't use an ImageButton?

Comment: Because i create a bunch of buttons dynamically by code. Normaly they all have text. But theres a special button if the text contains a special word which needs to load a drawable resource instead of a text,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like theres no way using padding of a bitmap within layer-list. I just decreased the bitmap size and now it fits in the button perfectly. But i don't know if it is looking same sized on every device...

Answer (score 0):

You can put icon straight in item element, like this:

```
<item
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```